# How to passing variables from php to react.js component?

Tags: php, javascript, reactjs

For example, I have a react.js component named `Question` which need the props `title`,`id`,`content`.

```
<div id="main-section">
    <div id="question"></div>
</div>

ReactDOM.render(
    <Question id="xxxx" title="xxx" content="xxx"/>,
    document.getElementById('question')
);
```

I come up with two methods:

1. design an restful api, everytime the web need to render a question, make an ajax request to the server to get the props.
2. store the props in dom element and get these props before rendering.

What's the best practise to do such thing? is there any other better method?

Answer (score 1):

You can define you `element` first as a const/var or whatever. Then you access the element's attributes with `element.attributes` and iterate through your attributes like so:

```
const element = document.getElementById('question');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Question {...element.attributes} />,
    element
);
```

You can access the attributes with `this.props`

If you're passing data-* attributes your can pass those with `{...element.dataset}`